# backone- saving to Database with nested views

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, backbone.js, view

So essentially I created a table in backbone. A row view of the model, that is contained in collection view of the table and the form where the user inputs the data. There are two cells in each row #itemName and #price. These recieve data from the textfields in the form #item and #price.

I want to save the list of rows to a Mongo database so that when the user reloads the page the full list will be kept in persistent storage. The problem is that I am confused on exactly where and how I should write my save statment. Do I tell it to do .save() the row view or do I tell it perform a .save() the full collection view? Any assistance would be appreciated. Im new to this.

```
$(function() {
    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    //collections
    var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item
    });

    // row view
    // the view of each item that will put on the collection view
    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        initialize: function(){
         // this is the new item view within the row
            this.template = _.template('<td><%- itemName %></td>'
            +'<td><%- price %></td>'
            +'<td><button class="complete">Complete</button>'
            +'<button class="remove">Remove</button></td>');
        }, 
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }

    });
    // collection views
    ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.items', //table body
        initialize:function () {
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);       
        },
        render:function () {
            this.addAll();
            return this;
        },
        addOne: function(item){
                var itemView = new ItemView({model: item}); 
                // append all rendered item view to the collection view
               this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
        },
        addAll: function(){
            this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        }
    });

    Form = Backbone.View.extend({ //form view
        el: '.item-form',
        initialize: function(){
        }, 
        events: {
            'click .add': 'addModel'
        },
        addModel: function(){
            var data = {
                name: this.$("#item").val(),
                price: this.$("#price").val()
        };
        // simple validation before adding to collection
        if(!_.isEmpty(data.name) && !_.isEmpty(data.price)){ 
            this.collection.add(data);
            this.$("#item").val('');// and empty these
            this.$("#price").val('');
        } else {
            alert('fill all fields'); 
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest using some loop constructs in your template to create all of your table elements from your model data, when you add data to the model you simply rerender the whole thing rather than all this DOM traversal. 
Then you can just save the model and do whatever you need to do. 

I have to run so I can't elaborate further now, hence the comment. Good luck.

Comment: You could do either depending on how you'd like to structure your APIs.  A `PUT` request for the entire collection, but I've also had success with a `PATH` request to update just the individual elements.  For the `PATCH` it might make sense to take advantage of Backbone's Events to notify the `ItemsView` on an `ItemView` change.

Comment: Im basically trying to just add a "whatever.save()" event i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to specify the `url` in the Backbone Collection:

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/items',
    model: Item
});
```

And then when you create the new "item", you create it using your Backbone Model specifying your data:

```
var item = new Item({
   name: this.$("#item").val(),
   price: this.$("#price").val()
});
```

Then add it to your collection:

```
var items = new Items();
items.add(item);
```

With this done, the Backbone Model will grab it's URL from the parent Collection, so when you save you'll be adding to the existing items:

```
item.save();  // this will send the data as a POST request to /items, creating a new item
```

Then if you ever update that model, Backbone will know it already exists and send a `PUT` request:

```
item.set("name", "a new value");
item.save();  /// this will send the data as a PUT request to /items/:id, updating the item
```